# Input string was not in a correct format Int32.Parse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Getting the error, when trying to execute this line:

```
spellPrefabs[Int32.Parse(spell.spellName)]
```

`spell.spellName` is a string equal to `"0"`

Can't get it, why is it not working. Any ideas? Am I just dumb and miss something obvious?

[image]

Comment: Double-check that `spell.spellName.Length` is 1 and `(int)spell.spellName[0]` is 0x30

Comment: Maybe you get this exception inside of your `Instantiate` method instead of this `spellName` parsing? Edit: This seems unlikely based on derHugo comment.

Comment: @SonerGönül pretty unlikely since [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) is implemented by Unity ...

Comment: Are you sure it happens in that exact moment and not maybe on a different call?

Comment: As @KlausGütter suggested do those items because sometimes you have zero width characters. I'm not sure if encoding could also have an impact. Might be useful for us to know how this string is loaded into the spell. Is it being parsed from some type of file? Are you using a library to parse it?

Comment: String is gotten from user input using `spellNameInputField.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;` gonna try what @KlausGütter suggested.

Comment: Seems like `spell.spellName.Length` is returning 2, which could be a whitespace I assume omitted by the VS debugger :(.

Comment: Re the downvotes: these are not votes on you, but on the usefulness and clarity of the question. You should not take this personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check that `spell.spellName.Length` is 1 and `(int)spell.spellName[0]` is 0x30. The debugger display might not show all the characters that are actually in the string.

If the string is from user input it might be a good idea to be prepared for such incorrectly formed input by either catching the exception or using [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).